# QtCritical: Could not connect to any X display

Tags: debian, permissions, display-manager

Installed `copyq` on Debian 10. When

```
root@engelsmann-vaio:/usr/lib# copyq
```

I get the error message: `QtCritical: Could not connect to any X display. (:0, )`

```
root@engelsmann-vaio:/usr/lib# env
```

gives me

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PWD=/usr/lib
LOGNAME=root
HOME=/root
LANG=da_DK.UTF-8
TERM=xterm-256color
USER=root
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
MAIL=/var/mail/root
_=/usr/bin/env
OLDPWD=/root
```

I reckon that what I *should* see - the program demanding an `X display` - is `TERM=xterm-256color`, but that is exactly what I *do* see...
Should not this `TERM=...` give `copyq` access to the X display?

When logged in as "myself",

```
morten@engelsmann-vaio:~$ copyq
```

I get

```
ERROR: Failed to create session mutex: QSystemSemaphore::handle: permission denied
```

Comment: The program I want to run, is [CopyQ](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/).

Comment: The question [What is a mutex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524/what-is-a-mutex) points me in the direction that I might have initiated `copyq` both as `root` and as `morten` on triggering the error mentioned towards the end of the question.But still, I am stuck...